# How do I get the GRUB menu to display?

Tags: 11.04, boot, graphics, grub2

I've been having [this](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/727620?comments=all) issue with my hp dv7t laptop. I fixed it using the recommended option: set GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash radeon.modeset=0" and run update-grub.

However, that caused a different problem. Before, even though ubuntu would go into a blank screen, the grub menu would always show. Now, GRUB loads (I know that since switching the "beep on load" option works), but I don't see the menu, or anything else, until the timeout is hit and the default option boots. This makes the system workable, but I don't like not having a recovery option and not having a grub menu in general.

There are no other OSs on the system, it's a clean install of Ubuntu Natty 64 bit.

Hitting shift after GRUB loads doesn't help.

How do I get the GRUB menu to show up?

Comment: After running `update-grub`, did you also run `sudo update-initramfs -u`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hold down the Shift key *while* your computer is booting up, and don't let go until it actually shows. (I have to do this on my desktop computer because the latest kernel breaks my graphics and I have to pick 2.6.38-10 manually).

Comment: This did not works for my case: http://askubuntu.com/questions/62907/how-to-stop-crashing-my-system-while-using-pci-x1-capture-cards-in-ubuntu-11-04