# How to stop crashing my system while using PCI-X1 capture cards?

Tags: 11.04, 10.04, video, kernel, capture

11.04 64-bit Ubuntu. I reinstall third times and just after installation i have this screen:

Now trying with BIOS to disable the PCI-X1 card somehow if i can login at-least else i have to use a liveCD mode to check the lshw.

[image]

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo lshw
ubuntu                    
    description: Desktop Computer
    product: ()
    width: 64 bits
    capabilities: smbios-2.7 dmi-2.7 vsyscall64 vsyscall32
    configuration: boot=normal chassis=desktop uuid=DEEB0A4A-7F52-11E0-8F74-0013D4D9C9F6
  *-core
       description: Motherboard
       product: DH67BL
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       version: AAG10189-206
       serial: BTBL1200086F
       slot: To be filled by O.E.M.
     *-firmware
          description: BIOS
          vendor: Intel Corp.
          physical id: 0
          version: BLH6710H.86A.0125.2011.0705.1517
          date: 07/05/2011
          size: 64KiB
          capacity: 960KiB
          capabilities: pci upgrade shadowing cdboot bootselect socketedrom edd int13floppy1200 int13floppy720 int13floppy2880 int5printscreen int9keyboard int14serial int17printer acpi usb biosbootspecification
     *-cpu
          description: CPU
          product: Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-2600 CPU @ 3.40GHz
          vendor: Intel Corp.
          physical id: 4
          bus info: cpu@0
          version: Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-2600 CPU @ 3.40GHz
          serial: To Be Filled By O.E.M.
          slot: LGA1155
          size: 3401MHz
          capacity: 4GHz
          width: 64 bits
          clock: 100MHz
          capabilities: x86-64 fpu fpu_exception wp vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe syscall nx rdtscp constant_tsc arch_perfmon pebs bts rep_good nopl xtopology nonstop_tsc aperfmperf pni pclmulqdq dtes64 monitor ds_cpl vmx smx est tm2 ssse3 cx16 xtpr pdcm sse4_1 sse4_2 x2apic popcnt aes xsave avx lahf_lm ida arat epb xsaveopt pln pts tpr_shadow vnmi flexpriority ept vpid cpufreq
          configuration: cores=4 enabledcores=1 threads=2
        *-cache:0
             description: L1 cache
             physical id: 5
             slot: L1-Cache
             size: 32KiB
             capacity: 32KiB
             capabilities: internal write-back unified
        *-cache:1
             description: L2 cache
             physical id: 6
             slot: L2-Cache
             size: 1MiB
             capacity: 1MiB
             capabilities: internal varies unified
        *-cache:2
             description: L3 cache
             physical id: 7
             slot: L3-Cache
             size: 8MiB
             capacity: 8MiB
             capabilities: internal unified
     *-memory
          description: System Memory
          physical id: 26
          slot: System board or motherboard
          size: 8GiB
        *-bank:0
             description: DIMM Synchronous [empty]
             product: Array1_PartNumber0
             vendor: A1_Manufacturer0
             physical id: 0
             serial: A1_SerNum0
             slot: DIMM3
             width: 64 bits
        *-bank:1
             description: DIMM DDR3 Synchronous 1333 MHz (0.8 ns)
             product: 9905471-011.A00LF
             vendor: Kingston
             physical id: 1
             serial: 4C2ADD9C
             slot: DIMM1
             size: 4GiB
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 1333MHz (0.8ns)
        *-bank:2
             description: DIMM Synchronous [empty]
             product: Array1_PartNumber2
             vendor: A1_Manufacturer2
             physical id: 2
             serial: A1_SerNum2
             slot: DIMM4
             width: 64 bits
        *-bank:3
             description: DIMM DDR3 Synchronous 1333 MHz (0.8 ns)
             product: 9905471-011.A00LF
             vendor: Kingston
             physical id: 3
             serial: 4B2BEE27
             slot: DIMM2
             size: 4GiB
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 1333MHz (0.8ns)
     *-pci
          description: Host bridge
          product: 2nd Generation Core Processor Family DRAM Controller
          vendor: Intel Corporation
          physical id: 100
          bus info: pci@0000:00:00.0
          version: 09
          width: 32 bits
          clock: 33MHz
          configuration: driver=agpgart-intel
          resources: irq:0
        *-display
             description: VGA compatible controller
             product: 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 2
             bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
             version: 09
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
             configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
             resources: irq:45 memory:f7400000-f77fffff memory:e0000000-efffffff ioport:f000(size=64)
        *-communication UNCLAIMED
             description: Communication controller
             product: 6 Series Chipset Family MEI Controller #1
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 16
             bus info: pci@0000:00:16.0
             version: 04
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pm msi bus_master cap_list
             configuration: latency=0
             resources: memory:f7c29000-f7c2900f
        *-network
             description: Ethernet interface
             product: 82579V Gigabit Network Connection
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 19
             bus info: pci@0000:00:19.0
             logical name: eth1
             version: 05
             serial: e0:69:95:a2:e2:8f
             capacity: 1Gbit/s
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pm msi bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
             configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=e1000e driverversion=1.2.20-k2 firmware=0.13-4 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=twisted pair
             resources: irq:43 memory:f7c00000-f7c1ffff memory:f7c28000-f7c28fff ioport:f080(size=32)
        *-usb:0
             description: USB Controller
             product: 6 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #2
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1a
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1a.0
             version: 05
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pm debug ehci bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=ehci_hcd latency=0
             resources: irq:16 memory:f7c27000-f7c273ff
        *-multimedia
             description: Audio device
             product: 6 Series Chipset Family High Definition Audio Controller
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1b
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1b.0
             version: 05
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=HDA Intel latency=0
             resources: irq:54 memory:f7c20000-f7c23fff
        *-pci:0
             description: PCI bridge
             product: 6 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 1
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1c
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1c.0
             version: b5
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pci pciexpress msi pm normal_decode bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=pcieport
             resources: irq:40 ioport:e000(size=4096) memory:f7b00000-f7bfffff
           *-pci
                description: PCI bridge
                product: Integrated Technology Express, Inc.
                vendor: Integrated Technology Express, Inc.
                physical id: 0
                bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
                version: 10
                width: 32 bits
                clock: 33MHz
                capabilities: pci pciexpress pm normal_decode bus_master cap_list
                resources: ioport:e000(size=4096) memory:f7b00000-f7bfffff
              *-network
                   description: Ethernet interface
                   product: DGE-528T Gigabit Ethernet Adapter
                   vendor: D-Link System Inc
                   physical id: 0
                   bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
                   logical name: eth0
                   version: 10
                   serial: 14:d6:4d:1a:b1:c9
                   size: 100Mbit/s
                   capacity: 1Gbit/s
                   width: 32 bits
                   clock: 66MHz
                   capabilities: pm bus_master cap_list rom ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
                   configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=full ip=81.164.42.157 latency=64 link=yes maxlatency=64 mingnt=32 multicast=yes port=MII speed=100Mbit/s
                   resources: irq:16 ioport:e000(size=256) memory:f7b20000-f7b200ff memory:f7b00000-f7b1ffff
        *-pci:1
             description: PCI bridge
             product: 6 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 2
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1c.1
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1c.1
             version: b5
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pci pciexpress msi pm normal_decode bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=pcieport
             resources: irq:41 memory:f7800000-f79fffff
           *-multimedia UNCLAIMED
                description: Multimedia video controller
                product: Blackmagic Design
                vendor: Blackmagic Design
                physical id: 0
                bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
                version: 00
                width: 64 bits
                clock: 33MHz
                capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
                configuration: latency=0
                resources: memory:f7900000-f79fffff memory:f7800000-f78fffff
        *-pci:2
             description: PCI bridge
             product: 6 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 4
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1c.3
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1c.3
             version: b5
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pci pciexpress msi pm normal_decode bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=pcieport
             resources: irq:42 memory:f7a00000-f7afffff
           *-usb
                description: USB Controller
                product: uPD720200 USB 3.0 Host Controller
                vendor: NEC Corporation
                physical id: 0
                bus info: pci@0000:04:00.0
                version: 04
                width: 64 bits
                clock: 33MHz
                capabilities: pm msi msix pciexpress xhci bus_master cap_list
                configuration: driver=xhci_hcd latency=0
                resources: irq:19 memory:f7a00000-f7a01fff
        *-usb:1
             description: USB Controller
             product: 6 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #1
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1d
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1d.0
             version: 05
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pm debug ehci bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=ehci_hcd latency=0
             resources: irq:23 memory:f7c26000-f7c263ff
        *-isa
             description: ISA bridge
             product: H67 Express Chipset Family LPC Controller
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1f
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.0
             version: 05
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: isa bus_master cap_list
             configuration: latency=0
        *-storage
             description: SATA controller
             product: 6 Series Chipset Family 6 port SATA AHCI Controller
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1f.2
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.2
             logical name: scsi0
             version: 05
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 66MHz
             capabilities: storage msi pm ahci_1.0 bus_master cap_list emulated
             configuration: driver=ahci latency=0
             resources: irq:44 ioport:f0d0(size=8) ioport:f0c0(size=4) ioport:f0b0(size=8) ioport:f0a0(size=4) ioport:f060(size=32) memory:f7c25000-f7c257ff
           *-disk
                description: ATA Disk
                product: WDC WD5000AAKX-0
                vendor: Western Digital
                physical id: 0.0.0
                bus info: scsi@0:0.0.0
                logical name: /dev/sda
                version: 15.0
                serial: WD-WMAYU2762677
                size: 465GiB (500GB)
                capabilities: partitioned partitioned:dos
                configuration: ansiversion=5 signature=000a06a4
              *-volume:0
                   description: EXT4 volume
                   vendor: Linux
                   physical id: 1
                   bus info: scsi@0:0.0.0,1
                   logical name: /dev/sda1
                   version: 1.0
                   serial: 3c48b46a-531b-4bfc-af13-b8f3b334ff5b
                   size: 457GiB
                   capacity: 457GiB
                   capabilities: primary bootable journaled extended_attributes large_files huge_files dir_nlink extents ext4 ext2 initialized
                   configuration: created=2011-09-25 23:06:00 filesystem=ext4 lastmountpoint=/ modified=2011-09-25 23:11:04 mounted=2011-09-25 23:19:12 state=clean
              *-volume:1
                   description: Extended partition
                   physical id: 2
                   bus info: scsi@0:0.0.0,2
                   logical name: /dev/sda2
                   size: 8097MiB
                   capacity: 8097MiB
                   capabilities: primary extended partitioned partitioned:extended
                 *-logicalvolume
                      description: Linux swap / Solaris partition
                      physical id: 5
                      logical name: /dev/sda5
                      capacity: 8097MiB
                      capabilities: nofs
        *-serial UNCLAIMED
             description: SMBus
             product: 6 Series Chipset Family SMBus Controller
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1f.3
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.3
             version: 05
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             configuration: latency=0
             resources: memory:f7c24000-f7c240ff ioport:f040(size=32)
     *-scsi
          physical id: 1
          bus info: usb@1:1.5
          logical name: scsi6
          capabilities: emulated scsi-host
          configuration: driver=usb-storage
        *-disk
             description: SCSI Disk
             physical id: 0.0.0
             bus info: scsi@6:0.0.0
             logical name: /dev/sdb
             size: 1910MiB (2002MB)
             capabilities: partitioned partitioned:dos
             configuration: signature=c3072e18
           *-volume
                description: Windows FAT volume
                vendor: SYSLINUX
                physical id: 1
                bus info: scsi@6:0.0.0,1
                logical name: /dev/sdb1
                logical name: /cdrom
                version: FAT16
                serial: 1f56-1ac9
                size: 1902MiB
                capacity: 1906MiB
                capabilities: primary bootable fat initialized
                configuration: FATs=2 filesystem=fat label=USB2 mount.fstype=vfat mount.options=ro,noatime,fmask=0022,dmask=0022,codepage=cp437,iocharset=iso8859-1,shortname=mixed,errors=remount-ro state=mounted
```

Comment: please run `sudo lshw` and edit into your question the output that corresponds to your capture card - if in doubt, put the whole trace into  your question.

Comment: @fossfreedom: i cant boot after first installation anymore. So i used my LiveUSB to boot. And somehow arranged this lshw info. Please see avove, also i included the screen shot, exactly how it looks after BIOS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If Ubuntu crashes, then that's a bug and you file those on Launchpad.net. As you point out, you should be able to get the hardware information from a 10.04 live session.