# Hide Grub menu and keystroke to reveal

Tags: boot, grub2, shortcut-keys, dual-boot

How do you have the grub appear on a key combination, but have windows boot default.

I'm running ubuntu 11.10 and grub 2.0.

Here is my current /etc/default/grub

```
# If you change this file, run 'update-grub' afterwards to update
# /boot/grub/grub.cfg.
# For full documentation of the options in this file, see:
#   info -f grub -n 'Simple configuration'

GRUB_DEFAULT=0
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=0
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET=true
GRUB_TIMEOUT=10
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=" quiet vga=769"
```

Thanks!

And here is my /boot/grub/grub.cfg http://pastebin.com/HbDBe8xz

Comment: You mean like <press shift> after BIOS post will launch grub menu?

Comment: Yeah any key combo will do.

Comment: it already exists, if your using grub press shift right after post and keep it pressed.

Comment: have a look [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/60278/how-do-i-get-the-grub-menu-to-display).

Comment: @brunopereira81 I'm trying to hide the menu so the user has no idea that the grub is installed and use a key combo to display it.  Unfortunately the grub always seems to flicker briefly no matter what values I set in /etc/default/grub

Comment: Using the same config of a single-boot Ubuntu PC doesn't help either. The lines quoted by OP is the same in the single-boot GRUB.

Answer (score 3):

I think you can do it with the config variables in `/etc/default/grub`. Don't forget to run `update-grub` after updating the file.

```
GRUB_DEFAULT= 3 #Assuming Windows is the third menu entry
GRUB_TIMEOUT=0
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=0
```

As per the documentation for each option:

```
`GRUB_DEFAULT'
     The default menu entry.  This may be a number, in which case it
     identifies the Nth entry in the generated menu counted from zero,
     or the title of a menu entry, or the special string `saved'.
     Using the title may be useful if you want to set a menu entry as
     the default even though there may be a variable number of entries
     before it.

     For example, if you have:

     menuentry 'Example GNU/Linux distribution' --class gnu-linux {
        ...
     }

     then you can make this the default using:

          GRUB_DEFAULT='Example GNU/Linux distribution'

     If you set this to `saved', then the default menu entry will be
     that saved by `GRUB_SAVEDEFAULT', `grub-set-default', or
     `grub-reboot'.

     The default is `0'.
`GRUB_TIMEOUT'
     Boot the default entry this many seconds after the menu is
     displayed, unless a key is pressed.  The default is `5'.  Set to
     `0' to boot immediately without displaying the menu, or to `-1' to
     wait indefinitely.

`GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT'
     Wait this many seconds for a key to be pressed before displaying
     the menu.  If no key is pressed during that time, boot
     immediately.  Unset by default.
```

Comment: ... the OP mentioned that Grub2 still displays briefly even with these values defined... Any ideas how to stop this?

Comment: Um, he seems to have GRUB_TIMEOUT=10, maybe changing it to 0 could help.

Comment: I think that setting `GRUB_DEFAULT` to `saved` is preferable for two reasons: 1) It remembers the last selection; and 2) it doesn't break if the number of menu entries ever changes (which *does* happen sometimes.

Comment: @roadmr No, 0 does not help. It flashes the GRUB background and no matter what is pressed, it does not bring up the GRUB menu. i.e. It goes to the default OS.

Comment: set GRUB_TIMEOUT=5, but edit `gksu gedit  /etc/grub.d/05_debian_theme` , set GRUB background color to black and menu_color_normal to black, so only highlighted items will be visible

Comment: @Denis That won't hide GRUB entirely.