# How can I disable GRUB from showing up?

Tags: grub2, dual-boot

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Hide Grub menu and keystroke to reveal](https://askubuntu.com/questions/70875/hide-grub-menu-and-keystroke-to-reveal)

I just installed another OS in my second partition.

I know that it is expected for GRUB to show up when you're dual-booting, but is it possible to disable that feature?

All I want is that GRUB shows up only if I press <kbd>right-shift</kbd>, just like when I had only Ubuntu installed.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How about just setting the timeout to 1 second (don't know if you can set it to zero or not)?  I don't remember exactly where to do this, but it's easily found, possibly in /etc/default/grub.