# How to get to the grub menu on lubuntu

Tags: grub2, lubuntu

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I get the GRUB menu to display?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/60278/how-do-i-get-the-grub-menu-to-display)

On a lubuntu (lightweight ubuntu) how do you get to the grub menu? (It doesn't appear by default)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Press shift before the system boots.

Comment: this worked for me. when I installed lubuntu and then android6-x86, on intel-powered-classmate.